# evaluating numerical integration for all sample observations

Tags: r

I need to calculate this integration numerically and then evaluating its value for each observation. I tried to do that using integrate function but each time I got  error message. here is my code:

```
    `rm(list = ls(all = TRUE)) # Remove all objects in R console
set.seed(123456) # Set the seed for reproducible results.default for the program to fix initial values to start with in each time.
install.packages("MASS")
library (MASS)  ## Simulate from a Multivariate Normal Distribution
n=10 # sample size
mu=c(0.3,0.7029) # true values of the mean vector of bivariate normal variables
var.cov<-matrix(c(10,0,0,10),nrow=2,ncol=2,byrow=T) #variance covariance matrix of the bivariate normal random variables    
y= mvrnorm(n, mu, var.cov)#generating the bivariate normal random variables
theta.rad=rep(NA,times=n)
for (ii in 1:n){
  if (y[ii,1] > 0 & y[ii,2]>=0) {theta.rad[ii]=atan(y[ii,2]/y[ii,1])}
  else if (y[ii,1] < 0) {theta.rad[ii]=(atan(y[ii,2]/y[ii,1]))+pi}
  else if (y[ii,1] > 0 & y[ii,2]<0) {theta.rad[ii]=atan(y[ii,2]/y[ii,1])+2*pi}
  else if (y[ii,1] == 0 & y[ii,2]>0) {theta.rad[ii]=pi/2}
  else if (y[ii,1] ==0 & y[ii,2]<0) {theta.rad[ii]=3*pi/2}
}# calculating the angles
u=cbind(cos(theta.rad),sin(theta.rad)) #constructing the main matrix (cos(theta,sin(theat)))
integral=function(uu){
  f=function(r){
  t=1/sqrt(var.cov[1,1])
  tt=t*uu%*%mu
  phi=log(1+((tt*pnorm(tt))/dnorm(tt)))
  aa=r*(exp((log(r/var.1))-(r^2/(2*var.1))+(r*(uu%*%mu)/var.1)-phi))
  return(aa)
  }
  integrate(f,0,Inf)
}
integral(u)
```

I got these error messages:
Error in f(x, ...) : 
  dims [product 10] do not match the length of object [15]
In addition: Warning message:
In r * (uu %*% mu) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Error in f(x, ...) : 
  dims [product 10] do not match the length of object [15]
In addition: Warning message:
In r * (uu %*% mu) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Answer (score 0):

Integrate requires a vectorised function `f`. Extract your f out of your nested integral function. Test `f` with the inputs `1` and `1:10` and see what happens. `integrate` is trying to multply  a vector `r` by an `n * 2` matrix (`uu %*% mu`) and it can't do that because `r` isn't necessarily of length `n` (or some multiple thereof).

Comment: Thanks alot for your reply but even when I extracted integration function and tried to get the value for the first observation I still have the error message .I modified the cods as follows `    f=function(r){  
  q=1/sqrt(var.cov[1,1])  
  tt=q*u[1,]%*%mu  
  phi=log(1+((tt*pnorm(tt))/dnorm(tt)))  
  aa=r*(exp((log(r/var.1))-(r^2/(2*var.1))+(r*(u[1,]%*%mu)/var.1)-phi))  
  return(aa)  
}  
integrate(f,0,Inf)`

Comment: I got error message:In (log(r/var.1)) - (r^2/(2 * var.1)) + (r * (u[1, ] %*%  ... :
  Recycling array of length 1 in vector-array arithmetic is deprecated.
  Use c() or as.vector() instead.

Comment: You could try f(c(1)).